# css variables - declare variable if not already defined

Tags: css, css-variables

I have a project which is split up into the parent app, and several reusable child components in separate repositories.  I'd like to define default CSS variables in these child components, which can be overridden by the parent app, however I can't find the right syntax for this.  Here's what I've tried:

```
/* parent */
:root {
  --color: blue;
}

/* child */
:root {
  --color: var(--color, green);
}

.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: var(--color, red);
}
```

https://codepen.io/daviestar/pen/brModx

The color should be blue, but when the child `:root` is defined, the color is actually red, at least in Chrome.

Is there a correct approach for this?  In SASS you can add a `!default` flag to your child variables which basically means 'declare if it's not already declared'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS stands for `cascading style sheets`, 
so you cannot override anything by a parent...

The only way is to create a **stronger rule**.

look at `.c1` and `.p1`

```css
.parent {
  --background: red;
}

.child {
  --size: 30px;
  --background: green; /* this wins */

  background-color: var(--background);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
}

.p1 .c1 {
  --background: red; /* this wins */
}

.c1 {
  --size: 30px;
  --background: green;

  background-color: var(--background);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>  
</div>

<hr />

<div class="p1">
  <div class="c1"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: does it suit for you?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Hitmands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4099454/hitmands) hint I have a neat solution:

```
/* parent */
html:root { /* <--- be more specific than :root in your parent app */
  --color: blue;
}

/* child */
:root {
  --color: green;
}

.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: var(--color);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why moving variables to the global scope could be neater?

Comment: My most common use case for CSS variables is for global stuff like `font-size` and theme colors, and it's this stuff I want to be able to override from the parent app.

Comment: Also using this approach means you don't have to add a new CSS rule in your parent app, ie. `.parent .child { /* override */ }`, you can let the variable specificity do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an approach by aliasing the variables in the component and using "parent" or root variables as main value while local value is by `!default`.

```css
.parent {
  --background: red;
}

.child {
  --child_size: var(--size, 30px); /* !default with alias */
  --child_background: var(--background, green); /* !default with alias */

  background-color: var(--child_background);
  width: var(--child_size);
  height: var(--child_size);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>  
</div>
<hr>
<div class="child"></div>
```

Comment: That's a neat approach, thanks